# Spring 4 RestController not mapping xml request correctly

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

[image]I am trying to make a restful Webservice that takes XML request and produces xml response and I am using spring 4.3.5 for it...

The issue is that when I am posting a post request using postman and add a debug on in my service method than I found that xml request attributes is not mapping/deserialize with player POJO.

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks

```
@RestController
public class SyncRestfulService {

LoggerManager loggerManager = new LoggerManager();

@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.SAMPLE_POST_PLAYER, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {
        "Content-type=application/xml" })
public Player getPlayer(Player requestEntity) {

    loggerManager.info(LoggerConstantEnum.SyncRestfulService ,
            "| <AbilitySyncRestfulService> Method: getPlayer " + requestEntity);

    loggerManager.info(LoggerConstantEnum.SyncRestfulService , "Id : ", requestEntity.getId());

    return requestEntity;
}
```

}

Request xml data

```
//Request 
<player>
    <id>1</id>
    <matches>251</matches>
    <name>Anand</name>
</player>

//response xml data
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <player>
    <id>0</id>
 </player>
```

//jaxb pojo

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "player")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Player {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String matches;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMatches() {
        return matches;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "matches")
    public void setMatches(String matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    }
}
```

Comment: add produces = {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE } in your controller

Comment: and do u have Configure bean to convert XML to POJO and vice versa in application-context.xml file

Comment: Correct if I am wrong, I think in spring 4 we are not required to add a converter. and its producing XML correctly I have tested that but In case issue is in mapping post body xml string to "Playter playter"

Comment: It is actually working as designed... The main problem here is that you forgot the `@RequestBody` annotation on the `Player` argument in your controllers method. Spring isn ow merely creating a new instance to do parameter binding, but as you aren't passing parameters in the url (or as form) nothing will be bound. You ar actually passing XML as the body and you need to instruct spring to do marshaling for that (instead of binding).

Comment: As from spring 4 with restController we can avoid the requestBody and responseBody annotation

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks... It's woking with RequstBody (Y) Can you post the same comment in answer section. So I can accept this :)

Comment: Thanks @MonisMajeed for your help

Comment: @AnandKushwaha `@RestController` is a combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` NOT `@RequestBody`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-restcontroller (which explains just that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Player getPlayer(Player requestEntity) { ... }
```

This is your request handling method (omitting the `@RequestMapping` annotation here). With this method you could do parameter binding to objects. So if you would pass the URL `/player/?id=2&name=foo` then the `id` field would get the value `2` and the `name` field value `foo`.

However you don't want to do binding you want to do message conversion. To enable this your method argument has to be annotated with `@RequestBody` this will tell Spring MVC not the use parameter binding but try and detect a suitable `HttpMessageConverter` to convert the HTTP message body to a `Player` instance.

```
public Player getPlayer(@RequestBody Player requestEntity) { ... }
```

The signature above should fix your issue. See also the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) which explains this quite nicely.

**Note:** `@RestController` is a combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` it does not infer the `@RequestBody`. See the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-restcontroller).